# how to use two same ViewController.xib in tabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i use a  tabBarController to show photos,  and each kind of photos are show in each tab,
 so i use one ViewController.xib , and how to show different content(Navigation Item and ImageView) in each tab ?

and my question is : 
where and how to write codes next step, does the codes in -(void)tabBarController or in PhotoController.m ? –

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
UIViewController *photoController1 = [[[PhotoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *photoController2 = [[[PhotoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                         ,photoController1
                                         ,photoController2
                                         ,nil];
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{       
    switch (tabBarController.selectedIndex) 
{
    case 4:     
        //how to write code;
        break;
    case 5:
        //how to write code;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? does your solution for two controllers work or not? the idea of creating multiple instances of the same controller is okay.

Comment: butthank you ，John Smith。 the two controllers works， but

Comment: （pls ingore the above comment,ha ) thank you ，John Smith。 the two controllers works， but i dont‘t know where and how to write codes next step,  does the codes in -(void)tabBarController or in PhotoController.m ?

Comment: Please go to Youtube , and search for tutorials using `TabBarController`. You can learn much better :)

Comment: thanks Legoias,  in my country, we can't open many web site, such as Youtube, Facebook, Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some prepare method in your PhotoController, and make it public, so you can call it from tabBarController didSelectViewController, so the code may look like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {       
    switch (tabBarController.selectedIndex)  {
    case 4:     
            //configure options for photoController
            [viewController prepareForDisplayWithOptions:options];
        break;
    case 5:
            //configure options for photoController2
            [viewController prepareForDisplayWithOptions:options2];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

}